# translating a d3 tooltip with i18next

Tags: javascript, d3.js, i18next

is there a way to apply the `data-i18n` attribute to d3 tooltips?
or, to put it another way:
it here a way to make it work?

i have a tooltip:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr("class", "tip")
  .offset([-10,50])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<span>" + d.amountCorrect + "/"
      + d.amountTaken
      + " ("
      + Math.floor((d.amountCorrect/d.amountTaken) * 100)
      + "%)</span>"
      + "<span data-i18n='markup.correct'></span>"

  });
```

that is supposed to show the percentage of correct answers given.
the last span is supposed to show "solved correctly" in different languages.

But it doesn't work.
it just doesn't get shown at all.

If i switch the language, i see the translation being inserted in the chrome inspector.
but as soon as i hover over the bar, it gets overwritten (with the "empty" span) and is blank again.

how can i solve this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What are the exact contents of the tooltip when you hover?

There is probably something wrong with the html contents you insert in the tooltip. Does it work when you remove the i18n?

Comment: it does work when i hardcore the text.
ok i have no idea how to post html here.
the html output is here: http://pastebin.com/svxadXD8

thanks :)